# “pulseaudio” works on one user and on another not

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio

I'm having a very strange problem with the audio server "pulseaudio" in one user I can use but in the other I can't, the only difference I have in the user that the audio works is that I load an extra module with these command:

```
pactl load-module module-remap-sink \
    sink_name=reverse-stereo \
    channels=2 \
    master_channel_map=front-right,front-left \
    channel_map=front-left,front-right

pactl set-default-sink reverse-stereo
```

I already tried to restart the audio server with `pulseaudio -k` output is error: `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process`

I also tried to delete the defective user's settings with  `rm -r ~/.config/pulse` but I was not successful

observing status with `` pulseaudio -vvv´´´ objective outpur is:

```
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 13.0
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 5a405607670141a3b9d4952899ff59fb.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 4.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1001/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/unip/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-13.0/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: System supports high resolution timers
I: [pulseaudio] cpu-x86.c: CPU flags: CMOV MMX SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 MMXEXT 
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] sconv_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized conversions.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_orc.c: Initialising ORC optimized volume functions.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup without any loaded modules, refusing to work.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon terminated.
```

as I'm using Debian SID that uses systemd I decided to see the log and the output was:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-08-03 11:01:28 -03; 13min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
    Process: 5573 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5573 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 03 11:01:28 debian systemd[5173]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 03 11:01:28 debian systemd[5173]: Stopped Sound Service.
Aug 03 11:01:28 debian systemd[5173]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 03 11:01:28 debian systemd[5173]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 03 11:01:28 debian systemd[5173]: Failed to start Sound Service.
```

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the log a lot and not getting close to solving or solving a problem in a desperation to reinstall the pulse audio, as Debian sid offers a "purge" option, I believe this tag was deleted in some conflicting situation

```
pulseaudio -k
sudo apt remove pulseaudio
sudo apt purge pulseaudio
sudo apt install pulseaudio
pulseaudio -D
```